# Mythic Black Tentacles vs. Freedom of Movement

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, mythic-adventures

My group has a question about [Mythic Black Tentacles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/black-tentacles/) vs. [Freedom of Movement](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-of-movement/). For reference:

The important parts...

From Black Tentacles:

> The tentacles can grapple creatures that are immune to grappling if that immunity is from a non-mythic source, but combat maneuver checks to grapple such creatures take a –5 penalty.

Freedom of Movement, broken down by me:

- Point 1:

> All combat maneuver checks made to grapple the target automatically fail.

- Point 2:

> The subject automatically succeeds on any combat maneuver checks and Escape Artist checks made to escape a grapple or a pin.

Our current thought is that if someone has FoM up and they're hit with Mythic Black Tentacles, they *can* be grappled, because the text of MBT overrides Part1 from FoM.

But then, on their turn, they can automatically escape because of Point 2 from FoM.

Does anyone else have this in play? What do you do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any examples of immunity to grapple that are not FoM based such as the spell or liberation domain? There was a simple monster template thing but thats still based off the domain. Even creatures that are immune to it, not counting immunity based on being incorporeal vs a corporeal creature trying to grapple.

Comment: There is no mythic version of freedom of movement (on d20psfrd) that would offer a counter point. Much like how the shield and magic missile versions would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Freedom of Movement Triumphs Once Again

[Mythic Black Tentacles](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Black%20Tentacles) states (emphasis mine):

> Augmented (6th): If you expend two uses of mythic power, the spell creates twice as many tentacles in the same area, meaning each creature in the area is attacked twice per round. The tentacles can grapple creatures that are **immune to grappling** if that immunity is from a non-mythic source, but combat maneuver checks to grapple such creatures take a –5 penalty.

Where as [Freedom of Movement](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Freedom%20of%20Movement) merely says:

> All combat maneuver checks made to grapple the target automatically fail.

Despite being mechanically similar, Freedom of Movement is not immunity to grapples (though it would not be unreasonable for a GM to rule otherwise).

What the augmented version of Mythic Black Tentacles does overcome are things like the [Deep Earth](https://aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Deep%20Earth) bloodline's Strength of stone ability:

> You suffer no penalties while squeezing through tight spaces and are ***immune** to bull rush, drag, **grapple**, reposition, and trip maneuvers*, and to push and pull effects as long as you are standing on the ground.

Comment: I would add that you can grapple when the effect of a FoM, (and thus ganing grappled condition), so it is not a grappling immunity